# How can you copy a Share Point solution in VS 2005?

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2005

I'm at my wit's end.

The Share Point guy got a brain tumor and had to quit, and they've tasked me with keeping this thing going.

Every year on the Share Point site, they put up a new Documents section for each of the departments.  They've got tons of forms and whatnot, and I really don't want to start each one from scratch.

Looking at his existing projects, it appears he somehow copied the previous year, changed the appropriate items - Year Number, some changes related to new people in positions, etc, and deployed.

I've looked all over the web, and can not for the life of me figure out how to do it.

Comment: If it wasn't such bad taste I'd be very tempted to make a SharePoint brain tumor joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like things that you do inside sharepoint rather than in visual studio.

Creating new document section and changing information is something that is done inside sharepoint, it is not programming of new functionality which is done in visual studio.

He may have automated this process, in that case you should look for a batch file.

Good luck

Shiraz

Comment: Thanks!  They just sent me the name of his box, and told me to remote to it and do it.  I saw the .sln, and thought, "Ok.  'solution'.  That's for VS."  Didn't even think there'd be functionality in Share Point to handle that.